# C++ собрать исходник

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция

Есть один исходник на Windows Forms.
И я не могу его скомпилить и запустить вот уже как неск. часов.

Всевозможные ошибки типа

> error lnk1120
>
> error lnk2001

и еще таких lnk.. было штук пять, какими способами я только не пробовал (настройки линкера не советовать, я его и вдоль и поперек... и в точку входа main и в подсистему windows).

Может тут найдется понимающий человек и намекнет что не так, а в самом лучшем исходе даст ссылку на мои исходники в собранном варианте (я почти уверен, что собрать его займет минуту-две, но у меня ну совсем не выходит).

[Исходник на Codeshare](https://codeshare.io/UoL4W)

Comment: Конкретней что не линкует? Файлы проекта? Библиотеки? В общем ошибки - в студию! В вижуал студии есть хороший вывод процесса линковки, где видно что за чем цепляется, и на каком месте валится.

Comment: Вывод линковщика с ошибками покажите.

Comment: в коде по ссылке нет функции main, может быть это не весь код?

Comment: @Mira вот картинка, так как скопировать и вывести сюда всю эту сумятицу будет трудно http://f4.s.qip.ru/tfn6TKWg.png.

Comment: @Cerbo в комментарии выше вывод ошибок.

Comment: @cybrex весь что есть.

Comment: @S.Stuart Ошибки надо в вопросе привести текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Исходник должен быть прямо здесь, в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильно указана `подсистема(subsystem)` в настройках `компоновщик (linker) -> система (system)`, этот параметр надо установить в `"windows"`. Причем будьте готовы что при пересборке проекта этот параметр будет слетать обратно на "консоль". Если же не "слетело" и стоит `windows` -все равно надо изменить - в этом случае на `"наследовать от родителя"`

Ну и main функция соответственно должна быть

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
);
```

"слетание" лечится, например, в cmake командой 
`add_executable_wrapper(${BIN} CONSOLE ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})`